# Disallow people to search you by phone number on Facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy

On Facebook, people can find you by searching the phone number you have linked to your account.

(Try it now.)

I’ve gone to *Profile* → *About* → *edit your contact and basic info* and it shows that the phone number is only visible to me.

[image: screen shot from contact information]

However, people can still search and find me by it.

I don't want to remove the number completely—because the phone number is good for recovering your account—, but I don’t want to be found by it. How can I disallow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is actually on the [Privacy tab](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy) in your settings.

[image: screen shot from Privacy tab]

Change it from "Everyone" to "Friends", and only people who you are in your Friends list will be able to find you by your phone number.